# ROS is not an OS but a framework, please reopen my question

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, incorrectly-closed

[ROS on BeagleBone Black?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/816178/ros-on-beaglebone-black) just got closed for being off topic with this message:

> This is not about Ubuntu. Questions about other Linux distributions can be asked on Unix & Linux, those about Windows on Super User, those about Apple products on Ask Different and generic programming questions on Stack Overflow.

however the [ros](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/ros) tag says:

> ROS (Robot Operating System) provides libraries and tools to help software developers create robot applications. It provides hardware abstraction, device drivers, libraries, visualizers, message-passing, package management, and more. ROS is licensed under an open source, BSD license.

ROS is libraries and tools, but not anymore. Now ROS is either a framework of libraries and tools or it's a standalone operating system at the discretion of reviewers. Now I need confirmation that ROS is a framework of libraries and tools again.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that ROS (despite its name) is not another OS but a framework to be installed in Ubuntu?

Comment: Yes, it's not another OS but a framework to be installed in Ubuntu.

Comment: or you need 1 meta post, 1 message in chat, 1 custom flag.. ;P

Comment: @karel Look like it has been reopened.

Comment: There's still an issue here - the tag needs to be improved to mention that this is not actually another operating system. Developers of ROS didn't really think their naming through

Comment: Why not rename the tag ros-framework or ros-tools

Comment: @Mateo I like "ros-framework".

Comment: @Serg right, they should've called it `ROFL` — `Robot Operating Framework and Libraries`.

Comment: @Hi-Angel Now that you mentioned it, I am not sure how the devs missed such an opportunity.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I edited the [ros](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/ros) tag to make it easier to understand, and I edited these other framework tags: [tinyos](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/tinyos), [katoolin](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/katoolin) and [zend](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/zend).

I will try to implement any requests for improvements in framework tags, since they may still require additional attention. Comment if you have a suggestion regarding a framework tag.

Answer (score 1):

From the official ROS site, about page (http://www.ros.org/about-ros/):

> The Robot Operating System (ROS) is a flexible framework for writing robot software. It is a collection of tools, libraries, and conventions that aim to simplify the task of creating complex and robust robot behavior across a wide variety of robotic platforms.

From this I can understand it is not an independent operating system, but tools and libraries that help make robot software.

Comment: Isn't that what the question says? What's the point of this answer?

Comment: @muru because of the discussion tag which means I can post an answer as a confirmation to a point in the question for who has an opposite opinion.

Comment: Or you could simply upvote the question, like the twenty others who have done so before you.

Comment: @muru  upvoting is confirmation without evidence, while something such as my answer is confirmation with evidence.

Comment: This post is pretty much long past the stage where any evidence is needed or useful.

Comment: The quote in the answer is beautifully written. Speaking as the person who last edited the ROS tag, it is not as specific about usage in Ubuntu as the ROS tag is, but I find much to admire in it.